# Why VS compiler insert a NULL into the object memory

Tags: c++, visual-studio

```
class RootBase{
public:
    RootBase():ai(12){}
    virtual void fas(){
        printf("%p \n", this);
    }
private:
    int ai;

};

class Base : virtual public RootBase{

public:
    Base():bai(1){}

    virtual void fas(){

    }
    virtual void fa(){

    }
private:
    int bai;
};

Base *pBase = new Base;
```

I test the virtual inheritance relationship case about memory location of class. The result surprise me， for the size of Base is 24 Bytes. I can understand the 20 Bytes which include the virtual function table pointer, virtual base table pointer and the member variable.

The memory distribution of the Base object pointed by pBase  is:

```
 60 77 41 00 68 77 41 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 54 77 41 00 0c 00 00 00
```

But I can not understand the meaning of the 13th - 16th Bytes , 0x00000000 ,a NULL(integer  0 in  x86 32bit) . What does the four Bytes 0 do? (OS : win xp , IDE :visual studio 8.0)

I also think that the integer 0 represent the alignment padding , but there is no reason to pad to 8 bytes.

Comment: I might not have looked closely enough, but padding?

Comment: Mummmmmmm~ But is alignment needed? I think this class is Four-byte alignment.No need to do padding.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/453x4xdd.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This taken directly from a dump of the object layout for the classes you're describing. I hope it answers your question. From a little more research I discovered that `vtordisp` for class `Base`. is an offset used when calling virtual functions from either the constructor or destructor of a class declared with a virtual base. Apparently its to inform them where *your* virtual function table is.

From [Jonathan Caves, MSFT](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/254670a3-9ba5-44d6-b9fc-d92840d200ac), over 5 years ago:

> It is used very rarely - but we have to add it to classes that inherit from a virtual base class and override virtual functions just in case the user does call a virtual function in the constructor or destructor.

Note: Sorry about the `1>` preamble on all the lines. Blame Microsoft, its their tools.

```
1>  class RootBase  size(8):
1>      +---
1>   0  | {vfptr}
1>   4  | ai
1>      +---
1>  
1>  RootBase::$vftable@:
1>      | &RootBase_meta
1>      |  0
1>   0  | &RootBase::fas
1>  
1>  RootBase::fas this adjustor: 0
1>  
1>  
1>  class Base  size(24):
1>      +---
1>   0  | {vfptr}
1>   4  | {vbptr}
1>   8  | bai
1>      +---
1>  12  | (vtordisp for vbase RootBase)
1>      +--- (virtual base RootBase)
1>  16  | {vfptr}
1>  20  | ai
1>      +---
1>  
1>  Base::$vftable@Base@:
1>      | &Base_meta
1>      |  0
1>   0  | &Base::fa
1>  
1>  Base::$vbtable@:
1>   0  | -4
1>   1  | 12 (Based(Base+4)RootBase)
1>  
1>  Base::$vftable@RootBase@:
1>      | -16
1>   0  | &(vtordisp) Base::fas
1>  
1>  Base::fas this adjustor: 16
1>  Base::fa this adjustor: 0
1>  
1>  vbi    class     offset   o.vbptr  o.vbte fVtorDisp
1>         RootBase      16        4       4          1
```

Taking the *exact* same code, but making `RootBase` a **regular** base class (i.e., not `virtual public RootBase`, just `public RootBase`) has a significant effect on the object layout:

```
1>  class RootBase  size(8):
1>      +---
1>   0  | {vfptr}
1>   4  | ai
1>      +---
1>  
1>  RootBase::$vftable@:
1>      | &RootBase_meta
1>      |  0
1>   0  | &RootBase::fas
1>  
1>  RootBase::fas this adjustor: 0
1>  
1>  
1>  class Base  size(12):
1>      +---
1>      | +--- (base class RootBase)
1>   0  | | {vfptr}
1>   4  | | ai
1>      | +---
1>   8  | bai
1>      +---
1>  
1>  Base::$vftable@:
1>      | &Base_meta
1>      |  0
1>   0  | &Base::fas
1>   1  | &Base::fa
1>  
1>  Base::fas this adjustor: 0
1>  Base::fa this adjustor: 0
```

Note that with the virtual base gone, there is no longer a "who-am-i" offset stored, which appears to clean up the object format rather nicely.

Comment: Thank you very much!That's the point!Vtordisp tells the program that because the derived class is not complete ,we can only find the virtual table of base class by Vtordisp , '0' means the pointer which now is called is just the address of base class virtual table ,no offset. Is my description right?

Comment: @whoscraig : Your code snippet shows vfptr twice (first code block: 0-4 and 16-20). As per my understanding vfptr for the class hierarchy is declared only once. So as RootBase already has a virtual table pointer, it will be shared by Base. So, I am still not able to understand from your reply, how can Base be 24 bytes, as for class Base the total bytes would be : 8 bytes for RootBase + 4 bytes for bai + 4 bytes for virtual base pointer + 4 bytes for vtordisp. That still leaves 4 bytes. How can these extra 4 bytes be justified, if not for padding?

Comment: @stamhaney that snippet (indeed all the layout hierarchies in this post) wasn't generated by me; it was created my ms's compiler. From what i can see one vfptr belongs to Base, the other to RootBase. Also note that without the virtual base class inheritance, there is, indeed, only one. I assure you I made no mistake in copying that hierarchy from my output window to this post.

Comment: @whoscraig, the second vfptr shown by the compiler is the _inherited_ one (from RootBase)